# How to read only the second last line of a file

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a client that updates/writes into `myfile.csv` arbitrarily.

I've written the following code, I left the MySQL snippet out:

```
while true
do
  awk_variables_value_array=`tail -n2 myfile.csv | awk -F, '$7 == "status" {print $4, $5, $10 }'`
  var1=${awk_variables_value_array[0]}
  var2=${awk_variables_value_array[1]}
  var3=${awk_variables_value_array[2]}

  if[ "var3" -gt "0" ]
  --MYSQL SNIPPET IS--
  fi
done
```

**Q:** `tail -n2` reads the *last* 2 lines, how can I change it is so it's the *second last line*

the file:

where *n* is the last line of the file

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
line 4
....
line n-2
line n-1
line n
```

current output yields:

```
line n-1
line n
```

I would like it so that the output is:

```
line n-1
```

Comment: You could add another condition to the `awk` command: `| awk -F, 'NR == 1 && $7 == "status" {print $4, $5, $10 }'` or write your own tool, e.g. like [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=987226&page=2)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

How about `tail -n2 myfile.csv | head -n1 | awk ....`?

Comment: so - `tail -n2 | head -1 myfile.csv | awk -F, '$7 == "status" {print $4, $5, $10 }'` ?
So essentially with this I will be reading the first line of the last 2 lines? ie the second last line? :) (I'm still relatively new to all of awk/sed/grep etc.)

Comment: @3kstc yes, this will read the first line of the last two, and then pass it to `awk`. This approach is much better than the alternative with `sed`, because it'll count lines from the end of the input file, without having to process all the data before that. On many-megabyte files you'll see a great difference in performance.

Answer (score 9):

```
sed 'x;$!d' <infile
```

That should work for you.

Explanation:
On each line [`sed`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) e`x`changes buffers (swaps contents of hold space and pattern space) and, if not on the last line, it `d`eletes the current pattern space (so nothing gets printed). Only on the last line `sed` autoprints the pattern space (which contains the previous line, i.e. second to last one)

Comment: Could you please explain how it works?

Comment: @Ruslan - there's not much to explain here, really. On each line `sed` e`x`changes buffers (swaps contents of hold space and pattern space) and, if not on the last line, it `d`eletes the current pattern space (so nothing gets printed). Only on the last line `sed` autoprints the pattern space (which contains the previous line, i.e. second to last one)

Comment: @don_crissti Your explanation requires someone to know what a hold space and a pattern space is, I think that's what Ruslan is questioning. For someone who doesn't know those terms (which you can't expect someone reading this question to know) your description doesn't explain anything.